# How to use socks with gradle for dependency resolving, in command line?

Tags: gradle, socks

When jcenter is not accessible without proxy server, to resolve dependencies, and i want to use socks instead of http proxy, how i can use it in commanad line?
I know how to use http proxy:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=yourProxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=yourPort  
-Dhttp.proxyUser=usernameProxy -Dhttp.proxyPassword=yourPassoword
```

Comment: You can set up proxy in **gradle.properties** configuration file. Just add this two lines to it:
`systemProp.socks.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.socks.proxyPort=1080`

Comment: It worked for me after i selected `Invalidate Caches / Restart` from File menu. (Android Studio 3.5)
Simple closing and reopening android studio didn't work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found answer, here you can use:

```
./gradlew -DsocksProxyHost=yourHost 
-DsocksProxyPort=yourHostPort your-command
```

using above you can set socks host and port.

Comment: How to set socks password?

Answer (score 10):

Gradle only documents about [how to use HTTP(s) proxy](https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_system_properties), however in the [ant source code](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=ant.git;a=blob;f=src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/util/ProxySetup.java;hb=HEAD) it mentions, there is enough information about how to setup the SOCKS proxy.

Add the following two lines to the gradle.properties configuration file and you are done.

```
systemProp.socksProxyHost=your socks proxy ip
systemProp.socksProxyPort=your socks proxy port
```

**The format of SOCKS configuration names (socksProxyHost and socksProxyPort) differs from HTTP proxy host and port configurations (http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort).**

Answer (score 2):

Refering to https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-set-gradle-proxy-to-socks/15508 
In the Project window change from `Android` to `Project` scope.
Then open up `gradle.properties` and add this line:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-DsocksProxyHost=yourHostIP -DsocksProxyPort=yourHostPort
```

`Sync` project.

Answer (score 0):

i might be a little late but i found out that in **ubuntu/Linux** the proxy settings are cached in  `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` and I also found out that this `gradle.properties` is different from the one in your app inside android studio.
so you need to edit the credentials in there.

do a `vim ~/.gradle/gradle.properties` and edit the credentials there.
in my case i was using a socks proxy so i commented out all the http and https proxy hosts and ports and added one for socks. it looked like this

`systemProp.socks5ProxyHost=127.0.0.1

systemProp.socks5ProxyPort=1080`

i was able to sync gradle afterwards.